# How many ways to choose 5 objects from 10 objects such that at least 3 objects are chosen from the first 5 objects?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I understand that you could choose
        $3$ objects from the first $5$ objects AND $2$ from the other $5$ objects
OR  $4$ objects from the first $5$ objects AND $1$ from the other $5$ objects
OR  $5$ objects from the first $5$ objects AND $0$ from the other $5$ objects,

leading to $(^5C_3\,*\,^5C_2)+(^5C_4\,*\,^5C_1)+(^5C_5\,*\,^5C_0)$ or $126$ ways to choose said objects.

But, $^5C_3\,*\,^7C_2$ also seems valid to me, as there would be $7$ objects to choose the other 2 objects from, once $3$ objects are chosen from the first $5$. But, $^5C_3\,*\,^7C_2 = 210$ ways.

So, which approach is the right one, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first approach is correct, and the second one overcounts.  For example, $\{1,2,3,4,10\}$ gets counted four times:
$$
\{1,2,3\}\cup \{4,10\}\\
\{1,2,4\}\cup \{3,10\}\\
\{1,3,4\}\cup \{2,10\}\\
\{2,3,4\}\cup \{1,10\}
$$